# Hot tablets problem possible when using App Engine auto-generated IDs?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The hot tablets problem is described here:
http://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/

I think I've read before that auto-generated IDs can suffer from this, I assume it's still the case?

If so, would a simple trick like inserting a random letter in front or reversing the order of the digits would help with this ? (I'm searching for a way to work around this problem while keeping keys as short as possible...)

Answer (score 1):

The ID numbers generated when you put a model in the datastore don't increase monotonically when deployed to App Engine (they do in dev_appserver).  You may see short ranges, but the numbers bounce around quite a bit.  I'm not sure if they do this specifically to defeat monotonically increasing indexes, but that's a side effect.

If you don't trust that, what I often do is create a key name using uuid.uuid4() (assuming you are using Python).

Comment: Sure you cannot get monotonically increasing IDs, but the hot tablets problem can still happen. UUIDs are a solution but they're very large and I'm looking for the shortest key possible.